# exclude HTML code from certain pages

Tags: html

OK. so i have a website, (obviously) and I'm trying to boost my SEO by putting so keywords towards the top of website. I have a template that was given to me by a third party but i have customized almost all of it except for the functionality parts of it. My page is organized by categories and when you enter any category the category name automatically gets placed at the top of the page using the code snippet:

```
<tr>
<td><h1 class="page_headers">[categoryname]</h1></td>
</tr>
```

it was easy to install this code into the frame of my site, and it works perfectly when you go to one of the category pages. the issue I am having is when you go to other pages that don't have a categoty. the code shows up as text as such

[categoryname]

is there a way to exclude a snippet of HTML on certain pages using java script or any other forms?

Comment: What populates [categoryname]? And what language does your website use? C#/ASP.NET? C#/ASP.NET with MVC? PHP? Something else? It would be helpful to provide more code.

Comment: what template engine are you using?

Comment: My appologies. the site is an .asp site. Im not exactly sure the specifics of it all.

Comment: if you would like to take a look the site is www.provisual.com, Im not sure if that helps any.

Comment: the template engine is 3dcart.com